# elasticsearch / kibana 4: field exists but is not equal to a value

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

elasticsearch version 1.4.5

kibana 4.1.1

logstash 1.5.2-1

**How do I structure a search in the discover tab of kibana 4 that only returns results if a field exists but is not equal to a specific value?**

I have some apache log data in logstash and I want to return all entries that have `status_code` defined but not equal to 200.  So if the possible values are {undefined, 200, 403, 404, 500, etc} I would like to see all variants of 4xx and 5xx errors but not messages where the field is not defined and not where it is set to 200.

I have tried the following:

```
+status_code: (*) -status_code: (200)

((status_code: (*) AND NOT status_code: (200))
```

I also see references to elasticsearch [curl queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745210/create-elasticsearch-curl-query-for-not-null-and-not-empty) but I'm not sure how to turn them into something that I can use in the kibana search bar.  Here is an example:

```
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "exists": {
              "field": "status_code"
            }
          },
          "must_not": {
            "term": {
              "status_code": '200'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The query you're looking for is this one:

```
_exists_:status_code AND NOT status_code:200
```

[This link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html?q=query%20string#_field_names) shows you all what's supported by query string queries.

Answer (score 10):

The previous answer is exactly what I asked for, however, this can also be useful:

```
 status_code:[300 TO 600]
```