# Ignoring records marked as deleted in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to process records only if `deleted_at` is *null* or *empty*. I modified my original query as shown below but for some reason the result won't change. I'm still getting deleted records.

I went thru similar SO questions and read up on [Exists Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-exists-filter.html), [Missing Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-missing-filter.html#query-dsl-missing-filter) and [Dealing with Null Values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_dealing_with_null_values.html) but failed to implement one.

**Analyser and the Mapping**

```
'settings' => [
    'index' => [
        'analysis' => [
            'analyzer' => [
                'snowball_analyzer' => [
                    'type' => 'snowball',
                    'language' => 'English',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
'types' => [
    'mappings' => [
            'deleted_at' => ['type' => 'date'],
    ],
],
```

**ORIGINAL QUERY**

```
{
  "sort": {
    "_score": "desc"
  },
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "user_id": "35ee78ea"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "age": "44"
              }
            }
          ],
          "minimum_should_match": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> The [missing filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_dealing_with_null_values.html#_missing_filter) is essentially the inverse of exists: it returns
>   documents where there is no value for a particular field

**MY INEFFECTIVE MODIFICATION 1**

```
{
  "sort": {
    "_score": "desc"
  },
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "user_id": "35ee78ea"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "age": "44"
              }
            }
          ],
          "minimum_should_match": 1
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "missing": {
                "field": "deleted_at"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**MY INEFFECTIVE MODIFICATION 2**

```
{
  "sort": {
    "_score": "desc"
  },
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "user_id": "35ee78ea"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "age": "44"
              }
            }
          ],
          "minimum_should_match": 1
        }
      },
      "filter": [
        {
          "missing": {
            "field": "deleted_at"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And which indices are you querying with that query?

Comment: I'm not familiar to ES. What exactly you mean by `indices`?