# Checking for not null with completion suggester query in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, curl, elastic-stack

I have an existing query that is providing suggestions for postcode having the query as below (I have hard coded it with postcode as **T0L**)

```
 "suggest":{
    "suggestions":{
      "text":"T0L", 
      "completion":{
        "field": "postcode.suggest"
      }
    }
  }
```

This works fine, but it searches for some results where the city contains null values. So I need to filter the addresses where the city is not null.

So I followed the solution on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14748761/2746086) and prepared the query like this.

```
{
 "query": {
   "constant_score": {
     "filter": {
       "exists": {
         "field": "city"
       }
     }
   }
 }, 
  "suggest":{
    "suggestions":{
      "text":"T0L", 
      "completion":{
        "field": "postcode.suggest"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But unfortunately this is not giving the required addresses where the postcode contains **T0L**, rather I am getting results where postcode starts with **A1X**. So I believe it is querying for all the addresses where the city is present and ignoring the completion suggester query. Can you please let me know where is the mistake. Or may be how to write it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to filter out suggestions at query time, because `completion` suggester use FST (special in-memory data structure that built at index time) for lightning-fast search.

But you can change your mapping and add [context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/suggester-context.html) for your suggester. The basic idea of context that it also filled at index time along with `completion` field and therefore can be used at query time with `suggest` query.

Comment: Ok, got your point. I think I will handle the null results on my application once it is fetched. Thanks a lot.