# unknown query [filtered] when doing search against ES

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to ES, and I am using ES 7.10.1, I have following simple search request:

```
GET /megacorp/_doc/_search
    {
        "query":{
            "filtered":{
                "filter":{
                    "range":{
                        "age":{
                            "gt":30
                        }
                    }
                },
                "query":{
                    "match":{
                        "last_name":"smith"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When I run the above query(using query and filter) in the Kibana Dev Tools, an exception occurs as follows, I would ask how to fix this,thank.

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "unknown query [filtered]",
        "line" : 3,
        "col" : 14
      }
    ],
    "type" : "parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "unknown query [filtered]",
    "line" : 3,
    "col" : 14,
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "named_object_not_found_exception",
      "reason" : "[3:14] unknown field [filtered]"
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40519806/no-query-registered-for-filtered/40521602#40521602

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [filtered query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/query-dsl-filtered-query.html#query-dsl-filtered-query) has been deprecated. You should now use the [boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html). Modify your search query as -

```
 {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "last_name": "smith"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "age": {
            "gt": 30
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```